# plotting loess with standard errors in R causes integer overflow

Tags: r, double, stack-overflow, loess

I am attempting to use `predict` with a `loess` object in R.  There are 112406 observations.  There is one particular line inside `stats:::predLoess` which attempts to multiply `N*M1` where `N=M1=112406`.  This causes an integer overlow and the function bombs out.  The line of code that does this is the following (copied from `predLoess` source):

```
L <- .C(R_loess_ise, as.double(y), as.double(x), as.double(x.evaluate[inside, 
]), as.double(weights), as.double(span), as.integer(degree), 
as.integer(nonparametric), as.integer(order.drop.sqr), as.integer(sum.drop.sqr), 
as.double(span * cell), as.integer(D), as.integer(N), as.integer(M1), 
double(M1), L = double(N * M1))$L
```

Has anyone solved this or found a solution to this problem? I am using R 2.13. The name of this forum is fitting for this problem.

Comment: If you can hack the code, can you change that piece to `L = double(as.double(N)*M1)` ?

Comment: `R 2.13` is quite out of date. A quick scan of the news sections shows improvements to `loess()` and `predict.loess` in subsequent versions. Try updating to `R 2.15.2` and seeing if the issue is still present

Comment: unfortunately i'm running R on a cluster and don't have much of a choice in this matter. i may try to copy this data set locally and plot since it's so small

Comment: Well, even if you can't run a new version etc. you may be able to hack the code of `predLoess` (`dump()` to a file, edit, change the name to `myPredLoess` to avoid confusion, and `source()` ...  (a quick look suggests the problem is still there in R-devel)

Comment: @BenBolker: good idea! let me try that. where did you see that the problem is still there?

Comment: I'm running r-devel, so I just glanced at the source of the file to see that the `L=double(N*M1)` was still there, and testing this statement with `N=M=112406` still causes an overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get predictions for all N=112406 observations. First, do you really need to do this? For example, if you want graphical output, it's faster just to get predictions on a small grid over the range of your data.

If you do need 112406 predictions, you can split your data into subsets (say of size 1000 each) and get predictions on each subset independently. This avoids forming a single gigantic matrix inside `predLoess`.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your first point? would you suggest forming `newdata` by `expand.grid` and running predict on that?

Comment: @Alex yes, something like that. I'm assuming that your model doesn't have too many dimensions, so `expand.grid` won't end up producing a huge output anyway.